# Graphics Accelerator Failing on Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: graphics-card, remote-desktop, remote-access, intel-graphics

My PC succesfully runs an Android Emulator application (Nox), which requires Graphics Accelerator, whenever I use it from the PC itself.
However, when I launch the application from my Laptop via Remote Desktop Connection (RDP), the application won't start or fails when its running prior.
I've read from a [blog](https://blog.tedd.no/2011/04/28/optimizing-rdp-for-casual-use-windows-7-sp1-remotefx/) that I need to enable RemoteFX but the problem still persists. I cannot use Chrome Desktop because policies are getting reset everyday.

Any advise on how to fix this or perhaps a better remote desktop application?

Both PC and Laptop Runninig on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had a read through that RemoteFX article - & even tried it out for myself. I don't think it will do what you think, though. It looks to me like a method of handling the screen updates over a restricted connection.

I don't think it will change RDC's apparent 'graphics card'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. how do I possibly run the application over RDC?

Comment: If it insists on hardware acceleration, you're unlikely to get it to work.